# Android - Adding side navigator from template

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-side-navigation

I have an existing app to which I would like to add a side navigator.
I realized that Android SDK provides a template for that (by adding side navigation drawer activity from the Add menu) but not sure about how to add it the app.

Here is the code of the sidebar class was generated:

```
package com.testapp;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

public class SideNavActivity extends Activity implements
        NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the
     * navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in
     * {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_side_nav);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container,
                        PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.side_nav, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_side_nav,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((SideNavActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments()
                    .getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

}
```

and here is the code of one of the activities I have:

```
public class MainMenu extends SideNavActivity implements IResponsable{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        final Button btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);
        final Button btnProfile= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_prfile);
        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new HttpGet(HttpClient.getClient(), MainMenu.this).execute("auth/logout");
            }
        });
        btnProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent prof = new Intent(MainMenu.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(prof);
                //finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void getResponse(Object iResult) {
        int code = Utils.ParseResponse.getResponseCode((Response)iResult);
        if(code == 200)
        {
            SaveSharedPreference.clearUserName(getApplicationContext());
            Intent menu = new Intent(MainMenu.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(menu);
            finish();
        }

        else if(code == 403){
            SaveSharedPreference.clearUserName(getApplicationContext());
            Intent menu = new Intent(MainMenu.this, LoginActivity.class);
            menu.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(menu);
            finish();
        }

    }

}
```

It also generated simple valid xml files.

When adding this activity in a new blank project, it works fine.

Thank you so much for the assistance!!

Answer (score 1):

With introduction of Android Design Library, the navigation drawer has been reworked and here you will find awesome explanation how now it works:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Also there is a sample project created by guys from Google:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Take a look at setupDrawerContent method here:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/support/android/designlibdemo/MainActivity.java#L111

and relevant layout file here:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml